# Crm 2015 custom action not fired plug in

Tags: crm

I new in crm dynamics 2015. 
I try create custom action. In firs step i create action in "process" in crm interface. After that I create project in visual studio as class library.I implement IPugin interface. I registrated my plug in on "message" that called as custom action name in "process". By when i try to use it it don't work. I run my plug in in debug mode for check if plug is called but it not

Comment: Are you trying to create a plugin or Custom Action. If its custom action then you have to inherit from CodeActivity not IPlugin. Can you please clarify this so that we can guide you correctly.

Comment: thanks for help i created action and inhered from IPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Renjith answered correctly. You should use the CodeActivity not the IPlugin interface as the derived class. Here are some libraries that might help you out:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx